# By Mistake i deleted system folder from root file and my mobile was rooted from then my mobile not working what can i do?

Tags: file-system

By Mistake i deleted system folder from root file and my mobile was rooted from then my mobile not working what can i do ? usb debbug is off flah file not found "reach cogent colours" plzzz help me ........

Comment: What is the phone specifications? Please provide further details regarding the phone.

Comment: lollipop, 1 GB ram, 8GB Rom, 4 Inch Screen

Comment: Phone make, model?

Comment: Reach Cogent Colours

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you can do in that situation is to flash a ROM. If you can flash the same ROM you just were using, you could even do a "dirty flash" (i.e. without wipe), so your settings and data stay intact.

For details, please see our [rom-flashing](/questions/tagged/rom-flashing) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom-flashing/info) and follow its links. What tools you will need depends on your device (which you didn't name). If you don't know where to find a ROM for your device, please refer to [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)